# Set NULL values in CF9 ORM

Tags: orm, coldfusion, null

Is there a way to get CF9 ORM to insert NULL Values into the database rather than an empty string?

I've got a numeric field which can be null, but throws an error because it's trying to enter ''.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Either:

```
yourEntity.setNumber(javacast("null",""));
```

or, add a removeNumber method:

```
function removeNumber()
{
    structDelete(variables,"number");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Henry,

Just need to work out a way to do this automatically rather than explicitly every time...

Maybe a pre-update eventhandler?

Comment: 2 ideas for you. 1.) use global event handler and convert "" to null at preinsert/preupdate 2.) extends a base entity class that has setNull(string propertyName)

Comment: If setting javacast("null,"") in controller doesn't bother you, use that. :)

Comment: I tried it using an eventhandler, but it threw an error. It seems that by the time it calls the preInsert() and preUpdate() methods, it has already checked to see if the datatypes are valid for the database table...

Comment: @Seb, may not work for you, but I solved this by using a base object with a generic setter which "wraps around" the built-in auto-setters - http://cfsimplicity.com/28/the-simplicity-of-jquery-style-generic-getters-and-setters-in-coldfusion-part-3

Comment: If you are using Coldbox the `nullEmptyInclude` attribute of the `populate()` method is extremely useful as the Coldbox _BaseOMRService_ handles the casting for you -http://wiki.coldbox.org/wiki/ORM:BaseORMService.cfm#populate

Answer (score 0):

A trick I learned somewhere along the way.

It's slower to call a ton of JavaCast("null","")'s than it is to call:

```
// slower
yourEntity.setNumber1( javaCast("null","") );
yourEntity.setNumber2( javaCast("null","") );
yourEntity.setNumber3( javaCast("null","") );

// faster
function getNull() {}
yourEntity.setNumber1( getNull() );
yourEntity.setNumber2( getNull() );
yourEntity.setNumber3( getNull() );

// we're talking microseconds difference, but it sure adds up.
```